# Django for loop in template won't loop through the elements it's like one big string

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to do a simple loop but in Django I can't get it to output properly.

It's printing everything like one big string.

In python it loops through fine and it is a valid list, created an inputted into the postgres database.

This is my function in my views.py

```
def pages(request, id):


   obj = rtves_programas.objects.get(id=id)

   context = {'title': obj.title,
              'show_date': obj.show_date,
              'script' : obj.script,
              'script_eng': obj.script_eng,
              'description': obj.description,
              'description_eng': obj.description_eng,
              'show_id':obj.show_id,
              'url': obj.url,
               }


   return render(request, 'rtves/pages.html', context)
```

this element is a list →  `'script_eng': obj.script_eng,` and I want to printout the elements of the list.

this is my code on the template.

```
{% if script %}
     {% for sentence in script %}
            {{ sentence }}
     {% endfor %}              

      {% else %}
          <p>Nothing here</p>

{% endif %}
```

But it's printing out everything in the list not the elements of the list, it looks like this

[image]

if I just add this to the template it `{{ script }}`

[image]

Similar to the loop but without the space

Here is the model definition

```
class rtves_programas(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)
script = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=8000))
created_on = models.DateTimeField()
show_date = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
script_eng = models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
description_eng = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
show_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a list? Show the definition of rtves_programas.

Comment: Your `script` is, If I understood it correctly, a single `str`ing, so if you iterate over it, then you obtain the individual characters. You can use `'script' : obj.script.splitlines()` to generate a list of lines. But that will normally have not much effect about formatting anyway.

Comment: when I print the type of the element it returns as a list. In the postgres database they treat arrays with the curly bracket not the square bracket and I can loop through it fine in python so it is a valid list.

Comment: When I iterate over it it just prints it as it looks in the Database starts with this {"

Comment: Are you storing this script data as a json string in the DB?

Comment: No, I create the list and then it's inserted as a list to the database. It's being treated as one string by Django

Comment: But as I already asked, you need to show that model definition, and explain how you're saving that field. Why should Django think it was a list?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the problem with the model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking at the models I decided to recreate them, I inheritable the tables from a legacy database and

```
class programas(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)
script = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True))
created_on = models.DateTimeField()
show_date = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
script_eng = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=8000, blank=True))
description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
description_eng = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
show_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Then the models won't update in the postgres database so I cleared migrations, so When the migrations didn't work

I ran this code

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."django_migrations";
DELETE FROM "public"."django_migrations" WHERE "id"=replace with your Id;
```

So now I can loop through but  I still have to work on a few other things.